# How to handle multiple keys for a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've been searching about how to go for adding multiple val for single keys in a Dict if a duplicate key is found.

Let's take an example:

```
list_1 = ['4', '6' ,'8', '8']
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
new_dict = dict(zip(list_1,list_2))
...output...
{'8': 'd', '4': 'a', '6': 'b'}
```

Expected output :

```
{'8': 'c,d', '4': 'a', '6': 'b'}
```

In order to process the above two list and combine them into one dict, i would face a certain challenge that we can't have two 8's in the 'key' of dict, which is a default behavior and i understand why !!

Some of the options that exists to process such scenario are :

1) Find if 'key' already exists in dict, if yes, then append the new val to 'key'

2) Create a mutable object to reference each key and in that way you can have multiple dup keys ~~Not really my use case

So, how can i go about for expected output using option#1 ?

Comment: Why not use set's as values to begin with?

Comment: Why a comma separated string when a list would make more sense ?

Comment: You want a `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `defaultdict`/`dict.setdefault`

Let's jump into it:

1. Iterate over items consecutively
2. Append string values belonging to the same key
3. Once done, iterate over each key-value pair and join everything together for your final result.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)   
for i, j in zip(list_1, list_2):
    d[i].append(j)
```

The `defaultdict` makes things simple, and is efficient with appending. If you don't want to use a `defaultdict`, use `dict.setdefault` instead (but this is a bit more inefficient):

```
d = {}
for i, j in zip(list_1, list_2):
    d.setdefault(i, []).append(j)
```

```
new_dict = {k : ','.join(v) for k, v in d.items()})
print(new_dict)
{'4': 'a', '6': 'b', '8': 'c,d'}
```

---

#### Pandas `DataFrame.groupby` + `agg`

If you want performance at high volumes, try using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : list_1, 'B' : list_2})
new_dict = df.groupby('A').B.agg(','.join).to_dict()

print(new_dict)
{'4': 'a', '6': 'b', '8': 'c,d'}
```

Comment: is this process fast, i have like like 1 million records in each list to process ?

Comment: @PetPan Yes, it is the most efficient solution here.

Comment: Dictionaries are pretty fast.

Comment: @PetPan if using option 1, use `defaultdict`. If it is still too slow, try my pandas option.

Comment: is there a reason why @U8-Forward solution works faster than pandas?

Comment: @PetPan performance on a list of 5 elements is not indicative. Pandas is designed to work fast with big data (you have a million records right?). At small sizes, the overhead does not justify its usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a `for` loop that iterates over the two lists:

```
list_1 = ['4', '6' ,'8', '8']
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

new_dict = {}
for k, v in zip(list_1, list_2):
    if k in new_dict:
        new_dict[k] += ', ' + v
    else:
        new_dict[k] = v
```

There might be efficiency problems for huge dictionaries, but it will work just fine in simple cases.

Thanks to @Ev. Kounis and @bruno desthuilliers that pointed out a few improvements to the original answer.

---

coldspeed's answer is more efficient than mine, I keep this one here because it is still correct and I don't see the point in deleting it.

Comment: you can avoid the wastefulness of the multiple `join` calls by using string concatenation instead (`new_dict[k] += ', ' + v`). Also you can simply do `if k not in new_dict` to not call its `keys()` method. You have a typo there too,

Comment: @coldspeed True, but better than multiple `join` calls.

Comment: `k not in dict.keys()` is O(n) (it's a sequential lookup), while `k in dict` is O(1) (it's a hashtable key lookup) and highly optimized.

Comment: Short answer: I was not as good as you. :) Interesting fact: for small lists this solution is more efficient than yours, coldspeed: with the OPs data it takes 1.88 +- 0.03 us for my code to run and 2.52 +- 0.09 us for yours. The situation changes with list sizes of 1000: 525 us for my code vs 184 for yours.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`setdefault`](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/not_using_setdefault_to_initialize_a_dictionary.html) dictionary function and get the index of it, then use try and except for checking if `idx` exists or not, i didn't get the index of the element every time because there are duplicates and at the end i format it so it outputs like Your desired output:

```
new_dict = {}
list_1 = ['4', '6' ,'8', '8']
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for i in list_1:
   try:
      idx+=1
   except:
      idx = list_1.index(i)
   new_dict.setdefault(i, []).append(list_2[idx])
print({k:', '.join(v) for k,v in new_dict.items()})
```

Output:

```
{'4': 'a', '6': 'b', '8': 'c, d'}
```

Comment: i can't believe, your code works way faster than pandas solution.
Took 0.0160000324249 seconds to run Pandas
Took 0.0 seconds to run Other

Comment: @PetPan use timeit for accurate timings. Also, you should measure performance on your actual data, I can tell you right away that this is going to be VERY slow for large lists because of the .index call inside the loop.

Comment: definitely, makes sense in what you shared, i was looking for the same info.